# Interacting with SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I realise this question could be quite broad but ive been searching for the past 2 days with no luck.

I've created a project in Visual Studio 2015 and created a new data source in that project using a cloud database created with SQL Server Management Studio.
I'm now trying to code a login page in the project, which gets a username and password from 2 textboxes on the UI and executes an SQL query to check if the user exists in the database and if their password is right.
I'm familiar with Java code for database connections, such as the prepared statement and resultset functions. 
Is there something equivalent for C#?

Thank you, reference to helpful articles or code samples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) seems pretty comprehensive

Comment: so if we make the long story short, you want to know how to check if username and password exist in MSSQL using Csharp or what?

Comment: do you want when user is typing in those text boxes?

Comment: @JohnHC Thank you!:)

Comment: @Badiparmagi Yeah i wasn't sure on how to execute the sql statement to check the database if the username and password exist. I know how to create the sql statement, just not sure how to execute it in the code of the C# project

Comment: Just to add, if you are going to do much database work in C# you should invest some time in learning LINQ.  Very useful.

Comment: You can check this also : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943772.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you :-

http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program

Answer (score 1):

here is probably the fastest but not the best way to check it.

```
string yourConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Users.accdb; Persist Security";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from UsersTable where UName = @Username and Pass = @Password"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPass.Text);

            using (OleDbDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (r.HasRows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User exists")
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User does not exist")   
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
   }
```